Что значит STL-совместимый контейнер в C++?
Я написал собственный кольцевой буффер, но мне сказали, что он не является STL-совместимым. Помогите пожалуйста и объясните, что значит STL-совместимый контейнер. Буду очень признателен!!

Скорее всего имеются ввиду следующие требования: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container
